# OS kernel also need to be paged?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, computer-science

While studying OS, I'm curious about OS memory management.

OS Kernel manages process by paging . Kernel is process, too.
Does Kernel also need to be paged and manged by something?
If so, What Component manages kernel pages?

Comment: In which operating system?

Answer (score 1):

> OS Kernel manages process by paging

Yes. Typically the kernel provides various high level system calls (e.g. maybe like `sbrk()`, `mmap()` or `virtualAlloc()`) that a process can use to tell the kernel what it wants, and the kernel does all the low level virtual memory management work (doing what the process wanted, and managing things like moving data to/from swap space and files, supporting various tricks like "copy on write", etc).

However different operating systems are different and the system calls the kernel provides can be higher or lower level and the responsibilities of the kernel can be different; especially for microkernels and exo-kernels where the goal is to reduce the amount of stuff done in the kernel (by moving it into processes in one way or another).

> Kernel is process, too.

Maybe. Different operating systems are different and for some its reasonable to claim that the kernel acts like a process (because the kernel has its own separate virtual address space). Far more likely is that the kernel acts more like a very special shared library that's mapped into every virtual address space and present for all processes.

> Does Kernel also need to be paged and managed by something?

Different operating systems are different. For almost all of them the kernel uses virtual memory. For some them kernel's virtual memory is set up during boot and then not changed after; so the kernel doesn't need to manage its own virtual memory much (and only needs to manage its own "heap" built on top of virtual memory, in addition to everything it does on behalf of normal processes). For some operating systems the kernel's virtual memory is managed (by the kernel) in a similar way to how a process' virtual memory is managed. In that case often certain features are limited (e.g. the kernel might support allocating virtual space and freeing virtual space and some tricks like "copy on write", but not support sending the kernel's own data to swap space or kernel pages backed by memory mapped files).

> What Component manages kernel pages?

Typically; the kernel manages the kernel's pages itself.

Note that all of the above is based on common "2 layer" models where you have a kernel and processes (and physical memory and virtual memory). In theory nothing prevents an OS from adopting a different number of layers (e.g. maybe "superkernel, subkernel/s, and processes" and/or with "physical memory, node memory and virtual memory").

Mostly; it all depends on what the OS designer felt like (which is strongly influenced by what the hardware designer gave them, but not strictly limited by what the hardware designer gave them).